# How to mutliply two objects by key and sum?

Tags: javascript, reduce

If I have two objects in javascript such that object a

```
  let relative_weight = {
      "Composure": 0.175,
      "Build": 0.128,
      "Strategic": 0.096, 
      "Career": 0.079,
      "Change": 0.062, 
      "Participative": 0.059, 
      "SelfAware": 0.055, 
      "Leading": 0.048, 
      "Taking": 0.047, 
      "Balance": 0.041, 
      "Putting": 0.041, 
      "Compassion": 0.039, 
      "Decisive": 0.037, 
      "Respect": 0.033,
      "Quick": 0.031, 
      "Confront": 0.028 
    }
```

and object b

```
let values = {
      Strategic: 1,
      Decisive: 1,
      Quick: 1,
      Change: 1,
      Leading: 1,
      Confront: 1,
      Build: 1,
      Compassion: 1,
      Putting: 1,
      Respect: 1,
      Taking: 1,
      Composure: 1,
      Balance: 1,
      SelfAware: 1,
      Career: 1, 
      Participative: 1
}
```

How can I multiple values in object a and b and then sum the results to produce a single value?

I looked up on SO, but didn't really find much that could help me; at least I couldn't tell what to do with those that I found. I did try some, but didn't work. Then, I realized, the one that I tried was a solution for python because I search for the term dictionary. I'm bit lost on how to do this in JavaScript.

Comment: I think Javascript does not guarantee to keep the order of the object keys as you write then in the code. Thus you need yo use Arrays or something that guarantees you that each value of the first object is multiplied by the proper one of the second.

Comment: @RashadKokash, thanks for the info. I'm using the `FormBuilder` in angular in which the group has the names. How can I associate it with the weights that I have ?

Comment: well, tbh, I am not familiar with angular nor form builder, but you might name your fields as the key of the first object then a hyphen then the key of the second object, for example the name of a field might be `Composure-Strategic` and when you want to multiply them, split the name to get the first key and the second one.

Answer (score 0):

```
const sums = []
for (let [key, value_a] of Object.entries(relative_weight)) {
    let value_b = values[key]
    sums.push(value_a * value_b)
}
console.log(sums.reduce((accum, current) => accum + current))
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple.  Find the keys of the objects.  You could start by assuming that the set of keys is identical (but you should confirm this assumption), then iterate through the keys and accumulate the sum of the product.

```js
let values = {Strategic:1,Decisive:1,Quick:1,Change:1,Leading:1,Confront:1,Build:1,Compassion:1,Putting:1,Respect:1,Taking:1,Composure:1,Balance:1,SelfAware:1,Career:1,Participative:1}
let relative_weight = {"Composure":0.175,"Build":0.128,"Strategic":0.096,"Career":0.079,"Change":0.062,"Participative":0.059,"SelfAware":0.055,"Leading":0.048,"Taking":0.047,"Balance":0.041,"Putting":0.041,"Compassion":0.039,"Decisive":0.037,"Respect":0.033,"Quick":0.031,"Confront":0.028 }

let result = 0
for (let key of Object.keys(values)) {
   // assumes that both maps hold the same keys, if either doesn't 0 will be added
   result += values[key] * relative_weight[key]
}
console.log(result)
```

This is actually logically equivalent to using the Array `.reduce()` method:

```
console.log(Object.keys(values).reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + values[currentValue] * relative_weight[currentValue], 0))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can loop objects with `for(.. in ..)`

```js
const relativeWeight = {
  "Composure": 0.175,
  "Build": 0.128,
  "Strategic": 0.096, 
  "Career": 0.079,
  "Change": 0.062, 
  "Participative": 0.059, 
  "SelfAware": 0.055, 
  "Leading": 0.048, 
  "Taking": 0.047, 
  "Balance": 0.041, 
  "Putting": 0.041, 
  "Compassion": 0.039, 
  "Decisive": 0.037, 
  "Respect": 0.033,
  "Quick": 0.031, 
  "Confront": 0.028 
}
const values = {
  Strategic: 1,
  Decisive: 1,
  Quick: 1,
  Change: 1,
  Leading: 1,
  Confront: 1,
  Build: 1,
  Compassion: 1,
  Putting: 1,
  Respect: 1,
  Taking: 1,
  Composure: 1,
  Balance: 1,
  SelfAware: 1,
  Career: 1, 
  Participative: 1
}
function multiplyObjects(objA, objB){
  const outputObj = {};
  for(prop in objA){
    outputObj[prop] = objB[prop] * objA[prop];
  }
  return outputObj;
}
function sumArray(arr){
  return arr.reduce((acc, val) => acc+val, 0);
}
console.log('functional programming version:', sumArray(Object.values(multiplyObjects(relativeWeight, values))));

// or you can only use a single loop for both multiply and add:

function operateOnObjects(objA, objB, operationFn){
  const outputObj = {};
  for(prop in objA){
    outputObj[prop] = operationFn(objB[prop], objA[prop]);
  }
  return outputObj;
}

function multiplyAndAddObjects(objA, objB){
  let sum = 0;
  let multipliedOutput = operateOnObjects(relativeWeight, values, (a,b) => {
    sum += a*b;
  });
  return sum;
}
console.log('single loop:', multiplyAndAddObjects(relativeWeight, values));

// to solve the precision error, multiply to ensure it is not a floating
// point number and then divide by the same afterwards

function customMultiplyAndAddObjects(objA, objB){
  let sum = 0;
  const sfAmount = 1000;
  let multipliedOutput = operateOnObjects(relativeWeight, values, (a,b) => {
    sum += a*sfAmount*b;
  });
  return sum / sfAmount;
}

console.log('precision fixed:', customMultiplyAndAddObjects(relativeWeight, values));
```

This is cleaner than for(.. of ..) which would require you to first convert the object to an array, for example with Object.entries(obj).